# How to clear form after successful submission?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submission

I'm having a problem regarding clearing form after submission. Problem is it clears form when it doesn't pass the validation(s). Means it keeps on clearing though I want to just clear it when the submission is successful.

Here's the snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inquiry').ajaxForm({
        target: '#error',
        success: function() {
            $('#error').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#inquiry').ajaxForm().resetForm();
        }
    });
});
```

Sorry for my bad English as well.

Comment: Read this useful post on learning jQuery: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/clearing-form-data

Answer (score 2):

try with `clearForm`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var options = { 
        target:        '#output1', 
        clearForm: true // clear all form fields after successful submit 
}; 
// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

see the doucment:

> **clearForm**
> Boolean flag indicating whether the form should be cleared if  the submit is successful
>
> Default value: null

### http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in method in javascript for clearing forms, it's called `reset();`

Answer (score 1):

[clearing an ajax form with jquery](http://drupal.org/node/814840)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var options = {
        resetForm:      true
  };

  // bind form using 'ajaxForm'
    $('#yourform_id').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myform").reset();
```

Comment: Oh my gas. Thank you so much geniuses! Sorry for the late reply though =P